# Twitter Login via Jsoup Java Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to login to twitter using Jsoup because I want to scrape my tweets and send them to me via SMS, I know how to process them from HTML and I know how to send them via SMS, I need help in Log In step, I'm not able to login to twitter
what I've tried is, processing webview in background(without any ui)(Note: No Ui of the app) but failed because it can't be processed without UI, with Jsoup I tried to login using this code

```
final String usernameKey = "session[username_or_email]";
final String passwordKey = "session[password]";
final String loginFormUrl= "https://mobile.twitter.com/login";
final String loginActionUrl = "https://mobile.twitter.com/sessions";

HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();  
HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();  

Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl)
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies());

doc = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
    .data(usernameKey, username)
    .data(passwordKey, password)
    .cookies(cookies)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .userAgent(userAgent)
    .post();

                /*
                 doc = Jsoup.connect(twitterHomePage)
                 .userAgent(userAgent)
                 .cookies(loggedIn.cookies())
                 .timeout(30 * 1000)
                 .get();
                 */
Log.d(TAG, doc.html());
```

But I'm not logged in and only getting Twitter Login page HTML

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use the twitter API that does this job efficiently?

Comment: Because I thought It'll keep my app light in size but twitter blocked me for logging in to my account using jsoup again and again and I think, now, I must have to use twitter API, can u please provide me a link to how to aign in using twitter API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Twitter blocked my account after only 2 logins from this method, try at your own risk.

Here is how I got it working

```
    Map<String, String> cookies;
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

Connection.Response loginPageRes = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl)
    .userAgent(userAgent)
    .referrer(refferer)
    .timeout(30 * 1000)
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .execute();

cookies = loginPageRes.cookies();

data.put(usernameKey, username);
data.put(passwordKey, password);
data.put("remember_me", "1");
data.put("wfa", "1");
data.put("redirect_after_login", "/");
data.put("commit", " Log in ");
data.put("authenticity_token", loginPageRes.parse().select("input[name=authenticity_token]").val());

Connection.Response resPostLogin = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .userAgent(userAgent)
    .referrer(loginFormUrl)
    .data(data)
    .cookies(cookies)
    .timeout(30 * 1000)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .execute();

doc = resPostLogin.parse();
    String timelineText = doc.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to reinvent the wheel by copying the codes from twitter api page so I will just link the **how-to for login**: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter

For **reading tweets** and other function: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/access-rest-api

Comment: I'm not a professional developer, so I did not get it that how to use this api with my UI less app

Comment: You don't need to be a "professional developer" to use the api. FYI, it can work same without UI. This is the recommended way that answers your question.